# Use function pointer in struct - C compiler

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I found an answer how to make function pointer in struct but I am still curious about 
its operation. Can anybody explain this clearly?

Here is my question,

This code runs properly but...

```
char func_1(void);    
char func_2(char);

struct mStruct
{
    char name[100]; 
    int age;
    char (*func_1)(void);
    void (*func_2)(char);
};

void init_struct(struct mStruct *pStruct)<-why this void function is necessary? 
{
    if(pStruct == NULL) {
        pStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct mStruct));
    }

    (*pStruct).age = 25;
    (*pStruct).func1 = &func1;
    (*pStruct).func2 = &func2;
 }

 char func_1(void)
 {
   ... ;
  }    
 char func_2(char)
 {
   ... ;
  }
```

I already tried to eliminate the `init_struct` function, but all tries failed.  My gcc compiler only accepts it as above.  Does anybody know another way to initialize the struct without using a function
or why it is only acceptable as a `void` function?

Comment: You haven't shown us the rest of your code. Something in there is invoking init_struct(), or it wouldn't be required.

Comment: Code like `(*pStruct).age` can be replaced by `pStruct->age`, it's more clear.

Comment: pStruct->age is totally same meaning of (*pStruct).age Any C compiler change pStruct->age to (*pStruct).age directly when compiling...And there is no other code.

Comment: func1 is same as &func1. function name gives address.

Comment: That code shouldn't compile; you call it `func_1` in the definition, but refer to it as `func1` in the initialisation function.

Comment: I'm almost afraid to mention the memory leak in that function. running out of wheels to come off.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking why it is necessary to initialize the struct?  By the way, your function is allocating a struct and initializing it, but after the function returns, you no longer know its address (it is leaked).  The `pStruct` parameter is passed by value, not by reference, so it will not have changed at the call site.

Comment: @user3304575 `pStruct->age` and `(*pStruct).age` are semantically exactly the same. But what Yu Hao said is about readability and clarity. That's why, in fact, we have the first syntax.

Comment: I know readability is important but it always depends on who program and it is out of the question.

Comment: "not leaking memory because I have enough memory" is a very wrong statement. A memory leak is a very serious problem with your code. Period. Fix it. Now.

Comment: So sorry I was trying to change my mistake but cannot change the comment. It was my mistake. I totally agree.

Comment: Thanks a lot pointing out mistakes of the code but all the answer is not really associate with my curiosity..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, besides the title, your question seems to have nothing to do with function pointers.

You have a struct `mStruct` with some members. For your question, it does not really matter what these members are.

With this struct, you don't *need* an initialization function.  You can always simply use the struct and initialize it:

```
struct mStruct s;
s.member = 20;
```

But, this comes with a cost: You repeat yourself and when you want to change the struct (say, add another member), you will have to change lot of places.  That's bad and can be fixed with an initialization function:

```
void init_struct(struct mStruct *pStruct)
{
    pStruct->member = 20;
}

struct mStruct s;
init_struct(&s);
```

Now, you should not add other responsibilities to `init_struct` than to initialize it.  In your example, you also *allocate* memory for the struct, in a buggy way.  Instead, use another function for that:

```
struct mStruct* create_struct()
{
    struct mStruct *pStruct = (struct mStruct*) malloc(sizeof(struct mStruct));
    init_struct(pStruct);
    return pStruct;
}

struct mStruct *pStruct = create_struct();
do_something_with(pStruct);
free(pStruct); // Don't forget this!
```

If you need more cleanup than just freeing the memory, write yet another function for it:

```
void destroy_struct(struct mStruct *pStruct)
{
    cleanup(pStruct);
    free(pStruct);
}

struct mStruct *pStruct = create_struct();
do_something_with(pStruct);
destroy_struct(pStruct); // Don't forget this!
```

Comment: Wow .. too much thanks for you. I also think my way is not a normal that's why I ask this question. Your answer release my stress out clearly.  and I am sure release memory also.. tc.